# Calculate the error using a sigmoid function in backpropagation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

I have a quick question regarding backpropagation. I am looking at the following:

http://www4.rgu.ac.uk/files/chapter3%20-%20bp.pdf

In this paper, it says to calculate the error of the neuron as

> Error = **Output(i) * (1 - Output(i)) *** (Target(i) - Output(i))

I have put the part of the equation that I don't understand in bold. In the paper, it says that the **Output(i) * (1 - Output(i))** term is needed because of the sigmoid function - but I still don't understand why this would be nessecary.

What would be wrong with using

```
Error = abs(Output(i) - Target(i))
```

?

Is the error function regardless of the neuron activation/transfer function?

Comment: ⁺¹ for the nice paper — couldn't find a single text that could unconfusingly explain backpropogation further than the error function and its application to the last layer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason you need this is that you are calculating the **derivative of the error function** with respect to the neuron's inputs.

When you take the derivative via the chain rule, you need to multiply by the derivative of the neuron's activation function (which happens to be a sigmoid)

Here's the important math.

Calculate the derivative of the error on the neuron's inputs via the chain rule:

```
E = -(target - output)^2

dE/dinput = dE/doutput * doutput/dinput
```

Work out doutput/dinput:

```
output = sigmoid (input)

doutput/dinput = output * (1 - output)    (derivative of sigmoid function)
```

therefore:

```
dE/dinput = 2 * (target - output) * output * (1 - output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - In the paper i refer to it says that this is needed because of the sigmoid function. If I was using any other function, would I still need to do this ?

Comment: You'd still need to do this, but the derivative part would be different according to the function you use. In the most trivial case, doutput/dinput is just 1 if you have a linear function.

Comment: Is it true for all cost function not just quadratic cost?

Comment: @I159 yes this works for any cost function. Obviously there are certain desirable properties for the cost function (smooth derivatives, a single maximum where gradient crosses zero etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The choice of the sigmoid function is by no means arbitrary. Basically you are trying to estimate the conditional probability of a class label given some sample. If you take the absolute value, you are doing something different, and you will get different results.

For a practical introduction in the topic I would recommend you to check out the online Machine Learning course by Prof. Andrew Ng

https://www.coursera.org/course/ml

and the book by Prof. Christopher Bishop for an in depth study on the topic

[http://www.amazon.com/Neural-Networks-Pattern-Recognition-Christopher/dp/0198538642/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1343123246&sr=8-1&keywords=christopher+bishop+neural+networks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198538642)