# Neural Networks and back propagation

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation, calculus

So I have a multi-layered neural network that succeeded in learning AND, OR, NOT and XOR. I have a doubt with back propagation.
I'm using the sigmoid function, so to determine the gradient of the error it goes something like this:

(Target - Output) * Output * (1 - Output)

But my question is, if I have a target of 1, and my output is 0, it would result in something like

(1 - 0) * 0 * (1 - 0), so it will tell me my error is 0, even though it's (I think) 1. Is it really supposed to be 0 or is it something I should account for when evaluating the gradient? Can somebody explain me what's the logic behind that 0? is it a local minimum of the function or something like that?

Comment: What error function are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think about it, it's gonna be that way even if your target is 1 and the output is 1.

The reason this doesn't happen is because you won't usually get a real 1 or 0 from a properly functioning backpropagation network, because you are using a sigmoid activation function at each node, so it's more likely that you get values that are close to 0 or 1. 
If you get 0 or 1 from your activations, it means the sigmoid saturated.
You can see how the sigmoid function behaves [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

**EDIT:** I think I should focus on the saturation.
So suppose you have a 1 at the output layer. This means that your sigmoid function returned 1, which means the value on the input was approaching to 6. If you look at the sigmoid plot, you'll see that when x is close to 6, the output is close to 1 and the derivative of the output would be close to 0 as well. This is a situation when we say the sigmoid "saturated". You do want to avoid situations like that. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Oh I see! This really clarifies it a lot; this is just what I needed, because at first I had that problem; It was solved by starting the net's weights with smaller values, but I didn't understand why. Now I understand it, Thank you very much.

Comment: Yep, larger weights were the reason. If you look [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf) you'll see others issues with backprop networks and many good ideas to address them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this question?

[Back propagation Error Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627773/back-propagation-error-function)

It says you need to work with the derivative of the sigmoid function for the error.